# PostgreSQL JDBC query: Include .sql file using \i

Tags: postgresql, jdbc

I'm using a JDBC driver to connect to a Postgres instance. During initialization, I'd like to load a full sql file. In place of `INSERT INTO Table(c1, c2) VALUES (v11, v12), (v21,v22)`is it possible to directly load the file using something similar to a `\i file.sql`?  `\i file.sql` itself doesn't succeed.

Comment: `\i` is a `psql` command, not a SQL command. You can't use it from within Java.

Comment: @RomanKonoval Thanks, I've voted for closing mine.